# pointer function delete? and pointer to pointer crash (c++)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm new to c++, and I use codeblocks

1/**pointer to pointer**:

```
int **pp = new int*;
cout<<*pp<<endl;
{
    int *p = new int;
    pp = &p;
    cout<< *pp<<endl;

}
```

After that if I write `delete pp` I have ".exe has stopped working". I guess it's because I try to delete the reference it's pointing to and it's not allowed. Do I just let `pp` be? Can't I delete it? Don't I have a risk of memory leak if I were to create lots of pointers to pointer?

1/**pointer function delete**?
I have:

```
int* fct_ptr(int &a, int &b)
{
    int* ptr=new int;
    if (a>b)
        ptr=&a;
    else
        ptr=&b;

    return ptr;
}
```

How do I deallocate the pointer I use for my `fct_ptr`?
Is writing `delete fct_ptr(int_value1, int_value2)`enough? But I suspect my `fct_ptr(int_value1, int_value2)` is simply a pointer who had its arguments' references through assignement, something like`int* a=new int; int*b=a;`, so it'd mean `ptr` cannot be deleted that way... 
So If I make several call of that fct  wouldn't I have memory leak?
I could just write `int* ptr;` and **not** `int* ptr = new int*;` To solve the matter.
But I want to know how to solve it without changing `ptr`'s declaration

Benoît.

Comment: Your `fnc_ptr` is wrong and produces a memory leak.  You allocated memory for `ptr` and then threw that value away by assigning a new pointer value, thus never getting a chance to deallocate the memory.

Comment: When you do `ptr = new ...; ptr = ...`, you overwrite the pointer returned by `new`. That's a memory leak.

Comment: There are no references involved in any of the code here. You are taking the address of variables, perfectly valid code in C, which does not support references. You need a good book.

Comment: @elan - Er, look at the signature of fct_ptr closer.

Comment: After causing a memory leak with `ptr = x`, you call `delete` on the pointer, which is an attempt to delete `x`. Since `x` is a variable on the stack (i.e. not created with `new`), you cause **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @paul so... I should never call `new` if I can't use delete? In this case my problem was to know why the compiler allowed it if it's wrong.  
I wanted to know how to deallocate the memory  outside the function, since I can't do it inside.

Comment: @BenoîtLu: You should not use `new` at all, unless you find yourself in extremely special situations which you are not even close to encountering while you are still a beginner. Use `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::unique_ptr` or other useful classes offered by the C++ standard library.

Comment: @beta what are you talking about? about my fct_ptr? or the first matter? 
About `fct_ptr` I'm *not using delete*, that's why I have a problem about it, because I need `ptr` for `return()`.

Comment: You say you tried to do it in the first case, and are wondering how to do it in the second case.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  There are a few options.  You could return a pointer to the correct parameter.  In this case, you never need to call `new`, and you should never `delete` it.  You could also allocate a new pointer, and copy the correct value into it.  Then you would call `delete` on that when you're done.

Comment: @donnie basically, just putting a bunch of intructions and see when it works or not, and understand why if it doesn't.

Comment: @beta Ok, you used other variable names it confused me. In my mind I separated the two matters

Comment: @BenoîtLu -- The problem is that `new` returns a value to you.  When you call `delete`, you must specify the same value.  You didn't do that -- what you did is that you took the value given to you by `new`, and then you threw it away by assigning over it another address.  What is probably confusing you is that you used the same pointer **variable** for `delete`, but it is not the variable that is important.  What **is** important is that you use the same **value** returned by `new` when issuing a call to `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to make sure you deallocate all memory you have assigned with `new`, do not worry about the pointer itself.

So with the first code block, when you reassign `pp` you already have a memory leak of the first object allocated (`new int*`), because when you assign `pp = &p`, you can *never* reach the memory adress of the previous memory object `*pp` was pointing to.

The rule is, for each `new`, there has to be one `delete`. So if you *really* want to declare with `T* p = new T`, you need to put

```
    int **pp = new int*; //(1)
    {
      int *p = new int; //(2)
      delete pp; //make sure (1) is deallocated, will never be reached otherwise
      pp = &p;
      delete p; //make sure (2) is deallocated, will never be reached otherwise
    }
```

For (2), the variable `p` only exists in the scope, and you can only reach (2) through it, thus you need to delete it in the scope as well. As stated in the comments, `pp` is now pointing to something undefined.

For the second case, every time you call the function `fct_ptr`, you allocate one `int` on the stack that never gets deallocated. So solution here would also be

```
int* fct_ptr(int &a, int &b)
{
    int* ptr=new int;
    delete ptr;
    if (a>b)
        ptr=&a;
    else
        ptr=&b;

    return ptr;
}
```

But of course, there is *no* need to allocate memory for what the pointer is pointing to if you're never using that object. Thus, just write `int* ptr;` if you're not intending dereference `ptr` before you are sure it's pointing to something.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
funny or not, I've never used a pointer past a delete, I always thought , indeed it was deallocating the memory the pointer was pointing to, but that the pointer was also "deleted". And I thought `new` was just preparing the pointer to receive something, so for me `int* ptr=new int; or int* ptr; int a; ptr=&a` were the same.

Comment: When you use `new`, you allocate memory on the heap, as opposed to the stack (as per your second example). Memory on the stack gets cleaned up by itself, but everything you allocate on the heap will be there until you deallocate it.